# JTable cells not changing the value after user input

Tags: java, swing, arraylist, jtable, classcastexception

I have a JTable which is updated from an arraylist. In GUI i have buttons for ADD, DELETE, MODIFY. When selecting a row i want to me able to press the MODIFY button and when prompted to input new values.
I have overrided the setValueAt and the isCellEditable methods, but nothing happens, the values remain the same.
Below is a compilable test example. The shortest that i could do.
Thank you in advance!

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;

public class GUI extends javax.swing.JFrame {
Test model = new Test();

    public GUI() {
        initComponents();
          jTable.setModel(model);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        jTable = new javax.swing.JTable();
        modify = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        tfName = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        tfPhone = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        add = new javax.swing.JButton();
        delete = new javax.swing.JButton();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jTable.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
            new Object [][] {
                {null, null, null, null},
                {null, null, null, null},
                {null, null, null, null},
                {null, null, null, null}
            },
            new String [] {
                "Title 1", "Title 2", "Title 3", "Title 4"
            }
        ));
        jScrollPane1.setViewportView(jTable);

        modify.setText("Modify");
        modify.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                modifyActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jLabel1.setText("Name");

        jLabel2.setText("Phone");

        add.setText("Add");
        add.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                addActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        delete.setText("Delete");
        delete.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                deleteActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
        jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
        jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(21, 21, 21)
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(add)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 73, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addComponent(delete)
                        .addGap(50, 50, 50)
                        .addComponent(modify)
                        .addGap(77, 77, 77))
                    .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addComponent(jLabel2)
                                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                                .addComponent(tfPhone))
                            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addComponent(jLabel1)
                                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                                .addComponent(tfName, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 129, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                        .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))))
        );
        jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 192, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel1)
                    .addComponent(tfName, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel2)
                    .addComponent(tfPhone, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 26, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(modify)
                    .addComponent(add)
                    .addComponent(delete))
                .addContainerGap())
        );

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void modifyActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       
         // TODO add your handling code here:
        String nrtel = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Edit phone number");
        model.setValueAt(nrtel, jTable.getSelectedRow(), 3);
    }                                      

    private void addActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                    
        String nume = tfName.getText();
        String nrtel = tfPhone.getText();
        model.adaugareContact(nume, nrtel);
    }                                   

    private void deleteActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       
         int selRow = jTable.getSelectedRow();
        if (selRow != -1) {
            model.stergeContact(selRow);
        }
    }                                      

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new GUI().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton add;
    private javax.swing.JButton delete;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
    private javax.swing.JTable jTable;
    private javax.swing.JButton modify;
    private javax.swing.JTextField tfName;
    private javax.swing.JTextField tfPhone;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}

class Test extends AbstractTableModel{

public static final int NAME = 0;
public static final int PHONE = 1;

     public static List<Contact> listaContacte = new ArrayList<Contact>();

      private final String[] columns = {
        "Name",
        "Phone"
    };

     @Override
    public int getRowCount() {
        if (listaContacte.size() <= 0) 
      {
         return 0;
      } else {
          return listaContacte.size();
      }
    }

    @Override
    public int getColumnCount() {
        return columns.length;
    }

    @Override
    public String getColumnName(int col) {
        return columns[col];
    }

    @Override
    public Object getValueAt(int row, int col) {
        if (col == 0) {
            return listaContacte.get(row).getName();
        } else if (col == 1) {
            return listaContacte.get(row).getNrTel();
        }
        return "Eroare";
    }

    @Override
   public void setValueAt(Object aValue, int rowIndex, int colIndex) {

      Contact abonat = listaContacte.get(rowIndex);
      switch (colIndex) {
      case 0:
         abonat.setName((String)aValue);
         break;
      case 1:
         abonat.setNrTel((NrTel)aValue);
         break;
      }
      fireTableRowsUpdated(rowIndex, rowIndex);

   }

//     @Override     
//            //olso tried this but "Object cannot be converted to string"
//   public void setValueAt(Object value, int row, int column) {
//     
//      Contact abonat = listaContacte.get(row);
//      switch (column) {
//        case NAME:
//            abonat.name = value;
//            break;
//        case PHONE:
//            abonat.phone = value;
//            break;
//
//    }
//    updateTable(row, column);
//
//   }
//   
//   public void updateTable(int row, int column) {
//    fireTableCellUpdated(row, column);
//}

     @Override
        public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int colNum) {
            switch (colNum) {
                case 2:
                    return false;
                default:
                    return true;
            }
        }

         public void adaugareContact(String nume, String tel) {

        Long s = Long.valueOf(tel);
        listaContacte.add(new Contact(nume, new NrTel(s)));

        fireTableDataChanged();

    }

          public void stergeContact(int row){

        listaContacte.remove(row);
        fireTableDataChanged();
    }

}

   class Contact {

        public String Name;
    public NrTel phone;

    public Contact(String n, NrTel nr ) {

        Name = n;
                phone = nr;    
    }

    public String getName() {
        return Name;
    }

       public NrTel getNrTel(){
                return phone;
       }

       public void setNrTel(NrTel nrtel) {
        this.phone = nrtel;
    }

              public void setName(String name) {
        this.Name = name;
    }

   }

   class NrTel {

    private long nrtel;

    public NrTel( long nr){

        nrtel = nr;
    }  
        public long getNrTel(){
                return nrtel;
       }
        @Override
    public String toString() {

                String str = ""+nrtel;
                nrtel = Long.valueOf(str);
               return str;
    }
}
```

EDIT:

I have modified this method

If a have 0 it modifies the first column. If i have 1 i get some errors

```
private void modifyActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       
    String nrtel = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Edit phone number");
    model.setValueAt(nrtel, jTable.getSelectedRow(), 1);
}
```

---

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to NrTel
    at Test.setValueAt(GUI.java:222)
    at GUI.modifyActionPerformed(GUI.java:133)
    at GUI.access$000(GUI.java:6)
    at GUI$1.actionPerformed(GUI.java:47)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2346)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6527)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6292)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2234)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4883)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2292)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4705)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4898)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4533)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4462)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2278)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2739)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4705)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:746)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:697)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:691)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:719)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:717)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:716)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:**

The error is in the `modifyActionPerformed` method. The problem is that the editor for column 1, the phone column, requires a `NrTel` object, not a `string`, so the `string` must be parsed into an `int`, then fed into the table.

Here is an updated method that will fix your problem:

```
private void modifyActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       
         // TODO add your handling code here:
        System.out.println("HERE");
        String tel = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Edit phone number");
        NrTel nrtel = new NrTel(Integer.parseInt(tel));
        jTable.getModel().setValueAt(nrtel, 0, 1);
}
```

**Old Answer:**

I believe the error comes from line 134 in the `modifyActionPerformed` method.

Here is your code:

```
model.setValueAt(nrtel, jTable.getSelectedRow(), 3);
```

Here is updated code:

```
jTable.getModel().setValueAt(nrtel, jTable.getSelectedRow(), 0);
```

The first part, `jTable.getModel()` is not necessary if the model object has the same reference number as the jTable, but it may be a good idea to use the accessor method.

The second part has to do with the number of the column. The columns are set up like arrays, starting at 0. Since there are only 2 columns, I think the third argument can be between 0 and 1.

Does this help?

Comment: How did you decide "3" for the column number?

Comment: no, just 0 and 1, but get some errors, see the edit, please. thank you!

Comment: Ok, I have updated my answer with a possible solution to your problem. I fixed the modifyActionPerformed method. Does it help?

Comment: You are welcome, I am glad I could help you out. Please up vote this answer if you found it helpful.

Answer (score 0):

When you call
    model.setValueAt(nrtel, jTable.getSelectedRow(), 3);

line 136

there is no case '3' in the switch in the setValueAt() method, so nothing gets updated

I tried changing to `model.setValueAt(nrtel, jTable.getSelectedRow(), 1);` so that

`abonat.setNrTel((NrTel)aValue);` is called, but then the aValue cannot be cast to type NrTel...

Guess you should change that to something like `abonat.setNrTel(new NrTel(aValue))`

Comment: i've tried to do abonat.setNrTel(new NrTel(aValue)) but (aValue)"Object cannot be converted to long"

Comment: Your right - you should try changing the phone field of Contact to type String instead